# RunDLL error message "MSIB4DE.tmp is not a valid Win32 application." when installing our software

Tags: windows-installer, windows-11

We have put together an installation package (using Wix) for software we've developed.  It has worked reliably for us over a number of releases and patches, and we have thousands of installed users.

However, today my coworker tried to do an installation on a new machine with Windows 11.  In the middle of the installation, he got the error message shown above, and the title on the error message box was "RunDLL".

I don't know what MSIB4DE.tmp is, but I would guess it is something in the windows installer code itself (hence "MSI...").  Or maybe it's part of Wix???

It appears that it is trying to execute this file as a DLL, but why would it try to execute a *.tmp file???

Has anyone seen this kind of thing before?  Is there a way to resolve the problem?

My search of SO and even the wider internet was not fruitful...

Answer (score 0):

The user reported that Windows updates fixed the problem and the installation is now succeeding.